A question about silent interval in Modbus RTU framing
I'm using a Modbus library here for an STM32 MCU which will act as a slave. And for a Modbus slave frame, there is something called silent interval. In the library I'm using the following section takes care of that(library example uses 115200 baudrate):
/* This function should be called in systick timer */
void uartTimer(void)
{
    if(RxInterruptFlag == SET)
    {
        if(uartTimeCounter++ > 100)
        {

            RxInterruptFlag = RESET;
            uartTimeCounter = 0;
            uartPacketComplatedFlag = SET;
        }
    }
}

So since I guess systick uses 1ms. The silent interval above is 100ms.
But when I read about the protocol here, it says the silent interval should be at least 3.5 character times. So for 115200 baud rate, assuming 11 bit per char:
silent interval >= 3.5 * (1/115200) * 11 = 334 μs
Now my question is, the protocol says this silent period "must be at least 3.5 character times". But it doesn't put an upper limit. And it seems in the example library I shared, 100ms is used which is more than 3.5 character times. But it could be 10ms or 20 ms or 500ms.
What determines a good value for this period? "must be at least 3.5 character times" does not tell me anything enough.

The silent interval is to detect interruptions and incomplete frames.
Standard
From MODBUS over Serial Line Specification and Implementation Guide V1.02, section 2.5.1.1 "MODBUS Message RTU Framing":

The receiver gap is 1.5 character times
The transmitter gap is 3.5 character times

When the receiver is collecting bytes it times the gap.  If the gap is small (< 1.5 character times), this byte belongs with the previous frame.  If it's larger, it belongs in a new frame.
The minimum for the transmit silent time is 3.5 character times, just to ensure it's nowhere near the 1.5 receiver threshold.  If a transmitter knows it's been silent for sufficient time, it doesn't have to wait.  There is no upper limit for the transmitter.
Diagrams from standard
Transmitting:

Receiving:

Code Fragment
I'd say that the code you showed is buggy, and a receiver should properly calculate 1.5 byte times.  However, in practice it's likely to not make much difference (physical interruptions might easily last longer; improperly joined frames will almost certainly fail checksum.)
At your baud rate, (1.5 * 11) / 115200 = 143 μsec., which is what the receiver should be testing against.  You might well use a value of (2.5 * 11) / 115200 = 239 μsec., if we're timing from interrupt to interrupt of a byte being available.


As jonathanjo explained, in Modbus when the receiver sees a silent interval of more than 3.5 character times, it should consider the packet complete and process it.
How to do it is another question. Back in the days of 9600bps, one interrupt would be raised per character, and the CPU would check a timer to see how much time passed since the last received byte. With modern "highspeed" UARTs it becomes a problem: UARTs now have FIFOs and DMA, and it's impossible to know exactly when a character arrived unless you disable these features and... trigger one interrupt per character to check a timer... which at 115.2 kbps or above, means a lot of interrupts. Also, faster bit rates mean if your UART interrupt must wait for a higher priority interrupt to finish, timings will be jittery. So you may be tempted to set the UART interrupt to high priority, but then your other interrupts will jitter too. It becomes a bit of a single-use CPU.
I wouldn't be surprised if modbus slaves don't handle the silent interval properly, unless they're pretty much single use MCUs at 9600bps.
This becomes a problem if the master is too fast:

Master issues a command to slave 1.
Wait time: silent interval + time for Slave 1 to prepare its response.
Slave 1 responds, master receives data.
Wait time: silent interval + time for master to decide to send another command.
Master issues a command to slave 2

All slaves are listening to all the bus traffic, and they determine if a packet is intended for them by reading the address. That requires knowing when a packet starts, ie detecting the silent interval. If the master doesn't take long between receiving slave 1's response and sending a new command, and if slave 2 messes up its silent interval detection by being too slow (say, 100ms instead of the standard time) then it will miss the interval between the end of slave 1's response and the master's new command, it will only see a stream of bytes made of the two packets. So in order to get the command, it needs to parse and ignore the first packet, notice there is extra data in the buffer, then parse it. This complicates things quite a bit...
So if you want your slave to be standards-compliant, it should consider any silent interval longer than 1.5 characters as an end of packet. If that's too annoying to do (too many interrupts, timing inaccuracies etc) then "close enough" should work fine, for example 1ms. If you do that, then the master should also extend its silent interval after transmission accordingly to make sure it is detected by all the slaves.
I guess if you're using 115200bps you want it to go faster than 9600bps, so it's probably not a good idea to set it to 100ms, as that implies the slave waits for 100ms before deciding the packet is finished, which would slow things down significantly.

So are you saying then the upper limit is related to how fast the Master is polling?

What I'm saying is, the standard is the standard, and if the receiver doesn't implement the standard (by being unable to detect short silent intervals) then it will break when the master polls too frequently. I think this is what you mean.
